# how can i use four animation one after another

Tags: android, animation

hi i have four animation,viz anim1,anim2,anim3,anim4.For the animation i am using the code as

```
        RotateAnimation anim1 = new RotateAnimation(240, 120, 8, 70);
        anim1.setRepeatCount(0);
        anim1.setDuration(18000);
        anim1.setFillAfter(true);
        img7.startAnimation(anim1);
```

i want to play four animtion one after another, ie at the end of anim1,anim2 has to play and so on....for the first two animation i am using

```
   setAnimationListener()
```

and it is working by giving second(anim2) as

```
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RotateAnimation anim2 = new RotateAnimation(240, 120, 8, 70);
        anim2.setRepeatCount(0);
        anim2.setDuration(18000);
        anim2.setFillAfter(true);
        img7.startAnimation(anim2);
    }
```

Now what will i do for the rest of the animation.Please some body help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Animation Listener,

[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)

Comment: thank you for your response.Just see the above code, there animation Listener is using and it is working when i am working  with two animation. ie here i am using two animtion anim1 and anim2.When anim1 is end, anim2 will play here.Now i want to add another anim3 at the end of anim2.HOW IT IS POSIIBLE? this is the problem ....i hope you get me